# html5 pushstate with MAMP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, vhosts, pushstate

I'm working on an angular website locally (using a virtual host and xip.io server alias), and using pushstate to pretty up the otherwise-hashbang-riddled urls. On the remote server, I'm able to use .htaccess along with a base href on the index to achieve this, but working locally, I haven't been able to get it working completely.

I can navigate the site and the urls change accordingly, but if I refresh the page, .js dependencies go 404 on me, and the page only half-loads.

This is the htaccess I've tried:

`# html5 pushstate (history) support:
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) /index.html [L]
</ifModule>`

This is what I used for the root-level htaccess, which had no effect. However, on the server, the htaccess file needs to be placed one level up from the root, so I did something similar on my local setup:

`# html5 pushstate (history) support:
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) dist/index.html [L]
</ifModule>`

Still no effect.

In googling, I find that this can be added via the vhosts file, so I gave that a shot, adding these rules to the `<Directory>` tag like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localmk.ilium1.com
ServerAlias client.*.xip.io
DocumentRoot /Users/mattk/Documents/ilium/web2014/BootstrapRepository/ilium-website-bootstrap/bootstrap/dist
<Directory /Users/mattk/Documents/ilium/web2014/BootstrapRepository/ilium-website-bootstrap/bootstrap/dist>

DirectoryIndex index.html

# html5 pushstate (history) support
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm just jumping into this stuff, and as such I'm pretty ignorant (in case that doesn't show here). I may or may not be asking the right questions. Any guidance is very much appreciated.

**EDIT:** After restarting Apache, the pages I was unsuccessfully trying to refresh previously began to do so. I got excited, answered my own question with "Restart the server," and went back to work happy... until I discovered that other views were still not refreshing properly. These view templates and URLs are one level nearer the top of the directory structure, e.g., the view at `/work/` will not refresh properly/completely, but the view at `/work/somethingelse` will refresh just fine. Console tells me `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html` for each of my .js filea (which are ultimately concatenated into one via Grunt), as well as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` for each. Previously these would simply cause a 404. No idea what's going on.

Comment: Things just got weirder... using the vhosts configuration, if I refresh the page with breakpoints activated in Chrome dev tools, it steps through and successfully reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this illustrates my noobishness pretty clearly. The answer is bone simple.

I neglected to restart Apache after editing the vhosts file.

Restarting the server worked like a charm. On to the next embarrassment...

Comment: Okay, here's the next embarrassment. This worked for refreshing some page views, but not others